# Obtaining list of Customers

Tags: balanced-payments

Is there any way to query balanced and obtain a list of customers via code?

Consider my site has many users, only some of them require a balanced customer id.
I could search my own DB and look for customers who have a balanced id assigned.
For the purpose of error checking I would like to query balanced and get their list of customers.

I know I can do this manually through the marketplace UI, this is not practical so i need to do it programatically.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  What language?  Relevant code?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Using PHP.
I cannot find where to start with this.
Have read through the API and it seems to realy on me sending the ID to balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/tests/Balanced/SuiteTest.php#L259

`$marketplaces = Marketplace::query()->all();`

Balanced's PHP client uses https://github.com/bninja/restful underneath the hood, so every resource has a static `query` method. Look @ https://github.com/bninja/restful/blob/master/src/RESTful/Query.php#L120 to see that this exposes a `all()` member method as well.

So, for any Balanced resource, in PHP, you can query it by saying `${RESOURCE_NAME}::query()`. In your case, if you want to get **ALL** the customers, then you can do:

`Balanced\Customer::query()->all();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a follow up question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256716/obtain-credits-for-a-specific-day
If you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about PHP, but with ruby you can access it via:

```
Balanced::Customer.all
```

If the PHP wrapper provides a Customer Object, I'd guess you'd be able to access it that way.

According to the [PHP documentation](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api?language=php#creating-a-customer) the object is accessible via:

```
Balanced\Customer()
```

Comment: Right, it's very similar in php (`Balanced\Customer::query()->all();`)

Comment: Thanks for the ruby pointer, I would rather have a helpful comment like this that I can possibly work with than no answer.