# Obtain credits for a specific day

Tags: rest, balanced-payments

I can use the following to obtain a list of all my credits

```
<?php
$marketplace = Balanced\Marketplace::mine();
$credits = $marketplace->credits->query()->all();
?>
```

I can modify this to obtain the credits for a specific customer

```
$credits = $customer->credits->query()->all();
```

Note the chance is from querying $marketplace to querying $customer.

Can I modify all() or by other means obtain credits with different parameters.
e.g. Credits in the last 24 hour or for a specific day,...

I know I can get the entire list of credits and then search though it but it seems resource hungry to get everything if only a sub-section is required.

Comment: In order to get the attention of users able to answer this question, you should [edit] it and add the applicable language [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: The question is specific to the tag used.  There are various language option within this.  I would prefer a php related answer hence the code but it is not essential.

Comment: My point is really that [tag:balanced-payments] probably isn't a popular enough tag to reliably get you an answer. If the question is about REST (which I guess only from the tag wiki for [tag:balanced-payments]), you should at least add that tag ([tag:rest]).

Comment: I interpreted your point as PHP, as that was the language I mentioned & rest is not a language.  Your clarification is well made and I have added rest as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can filter like this

```
$customer->credits->query()->filter(
    Credit::$f->created_at->lt($before),
    Credit::$f->created_at->gte($after),
)->all();
```

Here's another example on the internet that shows how to filter via the meta field too - https://gist.github.com/mjallday/5166040

Comment: Thank you I will try to use your code.
Regarding the example you linked to, I think it is missing ->save(); in some places to send the data to the balanced account.  Also when it creates $buyer->debit and $merchant->credit, it does not address the meta field although it does when it uses filter.